# pytesseract recognizing "P" as "J"

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract for reading single character images.
The images look like the following:

[image: letter T]
[image: letter K]
[image: letter P]

Recognition is working fine one every letter except the "P", that is always recognized as a "J".

Code:

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config='--psm 10')
```

Is there any way I could fix this?

Comment: I think you're best bet is try different psm modes. Try psm 4 and check the output.

Comment: I used `for`-loop to test different values in `psm` and I get `P` for `psm 8` and `psm 13`

Comment: thanks I will be trying, psm4 gave empty values sometimes, so I will try 8 and 13 now and let you know